# How can I filter dropdown select option with using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to filter (select name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName")according to (select name="HospitalName" id="HospitalName")'s value but it returns me zero item. What I want to do is for a user to select a hospital, then see the departments from that hospital and select one ("DepartmentName"). In other words, I want to filter the departments according to the selected hospital and offer the departments in that hospital as an option. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="input-group">
                            <label class="label">Hospital Name</label>
                            <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="margin-top:30px;margin-left:-120px;">

                                <select name="HospitalName" id="HospitalName">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>


                                    @foreach (var item in Model.hospitals)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.Id" data-rel ="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                                    }

                                </select>



                                <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label class="label">Department Name</label>
                            <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="margin-top:30px;margin-left:-150px;">
                                <select name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName">
                                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>

                                    @foreach (var item in Model.departments)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@item.Id" >@item.Name</option>
                                    }


                                </select>
                                <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                            </div>
```

**script code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    $(function() {
          $("#HospitalName").change(function() {
          $("#DepartmentName option").hide();
          $("#DepartmentName option[id^='" + $(":selected", this).data("rel") + "']").show();
```

**model**

```
public class ViewModel2
{
    public Patient patients;
    public Illness illness;
    public List<Doctor> doctors { get; set; }
    public List<Illness> illnesses { get; set; }
    public List<Hospital> hospitals { get; set; }
    public List<DAppDate> dAppDates { get; set; }
    public List<Department> departments { get; set; }
    public List<Appointment> appointments { get; set; }
    public Hospital hospital { get; set; }

}
```

**I can list the department's names but I can not filter that. when I chose "Medicana" I should list only "Nutrition and Diet" and "dermatology" because "psychiatry " is department of another hospital's department and should not be shown. No output options anymore. Additionally I should not create the option dynamically have to list them help of foreach.**

[image]

[image: view-source]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232401/discussion-on-question-by-learningwoman-how-can-i-filter-dropdown-select-option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matcher` method of `select2` plugin . So ,whenever user select any value from  1st select-box you can filter options inside 2nd select-box using `$(option[0].outerHTML).attr("value") == rel_` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").select2();
  $("#HospitalName").change(function() {
    //get rel value
    var rel_ = $(this).find("option:selected").data("rel")
    $("#DepartmentName").select2("val", ""); //remove any selected value
    //intialze
    $("#DepartmentName").select2({
      matcher: function(term, text, option) {
        //only show options where rel = value ..
        return $(option[0].outerHTML).attr("value") == rel_
      }
    })
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <label class="label">Hospital Name</label>
  <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="">
    <select name="HospitalName" id="HospitalName" style="width:100px">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value="01" data-rel="hosp-1">Hosp 1</option>
      <option value="02" data-rel="hosp-2">Hosp 2</option>
      <option value="03" data-rel="hosp-3">Hosp 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="label">Department Name</label>
  <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="">
    <select name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName" style="width:100px">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value="hosp-1">Item 1 h1</option>
      <option value="hosp-1">Item 2 h1</option>
      <option value="hosp-2">Item 3 h2</option>
      <option value="hosp-2">Item 4 h2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#HospitalName").change(function() {
    $("#DepartmentName option").hide();
    $("#DepartmentName option[value='" + $(":selected", this).data("rel") + "']").show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="label">Hospital Name</label>
  <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="">
    <select name="HospitalName" id="HospitalName">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value="01" data-rel="hosp-1">Hosp 1</option>
      <option value="02" data-rel="hosp-2">Hosp 2</option>
      <option value="03" data-rel="hosp-3">Hosp 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="label">Department Name</label>
  <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="">
    <select name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value="hosp-1" id="hosp-1-item-1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="hosp-1" id="hosp-2-item-2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="hosp-1" id="hosp-3-item-3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="hosp-2" id="hosp-1-item-4">Item 4</option>
      <option value="hosp-2" id="hosp-2-item-5">Item 5</option>
      <option value="hosp-2" id="hosp-3-item-6">Item 6</option>
      <option value="hosp-3" id="hosp-1-item-7">Item 7</option>
      <option value="hosp-3" id="hosp-2-item-8">Item 8</option>
      <option value="hosp-3" id="hosp-3-item-9">Item 9</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Added a Data attribute to help create a relationship. I also updated the ID so that there is something to tie to the relationship. When a User makes a change, it hides the items and only allows specific ones to be shown.

Comment: I edited the question please think about the things I wrote.

Comment: @learningwoman I reviewed your edits. They offer no further insight or examples. Please review the answer I post that shows some example HTML, populated with details I had to guess.

Comment: I already try this, nothing has changed. I edited the question as I tried, you can see details.

Comment: Can't hide option cross browser. Not supported in all

Comment: @charlietfl Mr charlie what i want to do is simly if the "HospitalName" value is equals to "DepartmentNames" value show it if its not equal dont show it?

Comment: @charlietfl could Enable / Disable them. Otherwise need an AJAX Call to get a list of Options to populate the Select.

Comment: @learningwoman made a minor update so it looks at the Value instead of the id.

Comment: Now when I do as you said, I get "no results found" output as I added in the question.

Comment: @learningwoman then we're back to needing to see the output to your HTML. Can you View Source on the page and show what you see.

Comment: @Twisty I edited the question. Would you take a look?

Comment: @learningwoman it looks like you are using a Select2 plugin, so my answer will not work at all. you will need to collect the selected option from your Select2 object and use that value to adjust the 2nd Select2 object.  Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty you are right! I am using select 2 plugin. Thanks for that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $select1 = $('#HospitalName'),
$select2 = $('#DepartmentName'),
$options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function() {
  var hosp = $(this).find("option:selected").data("rel");
  $select2.html($options.filter('[data-hosp="' + hosp + '"]'));
  $select2.val($select2.find("option:first").val());
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="label">Hospital Name</label>
  <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="">
    <select name="HospitalName" id="HospitalName">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value="01" data-rel="hosp-1">Hosp 1</option>
      <option value="02" data-rel="hosp-2">Hosp 2</option>
      <option value="03" data-rel="hosp-3">Hosp 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <label class="label">Department Name</label>
  <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search" style="">
    <select name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-1">Item 4</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-2">Item 5</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-3">Item 6</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-1">Item 7</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-2">Item 8</option>
      <option value="Item 1" data-hosp="hosp-3">Item 9</option>
    </select>
    <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the code you threw and nothing changed.

Comment: @learningwoman click the blue run code snippet button you can see it works as expected?

Comment: yes I am sorry this is just what I want but I can not run in my code ,in "data-rel" I have to send my hospital's id and in  data-hosp I have to catch my department's hid(hospital id).I am wrong?

Comment: @learningwoman yes thats correct the data-hosp value has to be the same as the data-rel value (the hospital) from the Hospital drop down

Comment: I did your code exacly for try but it gives me "no result found" after that I tried it in online html compiler it is work like we expect. What it wrong with my code? I edited my question and I added what the output looks like to the question.